# Check Host Connectivity by HostName/IP

Tags: powershell, host

I have this script which can check host connectivity by its name, but I want it to check the connectivity either by name or its IP address as sometimes I don't have the HostName with me.

```bsh
$ComputersFile = "HostName.txt"
$OutputFile = "Output.txt"

$Computers = Get-Content $ComputersFile

Remove-Item 'Output.txt'

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    try {
        $DNS = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($Computer)
        if (Test-Connection $Computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
            "$Computer^Yes^$($DNS.HostName)^$($DNS.AddressList[0].IPAddressToString)^ONLINE" |
                Out-File -Enc UTF8 -Append $OutputFile
        } else {
            "$Computer^Yes^$($DNS.HostName)^$($DNS.AddressList[0].IPAddressToString)^OFFLINE" |
                Out-File -Enc UTF8 -Append $OutputFile
        }
    } catch {
        "$Computer^No" | Out-File -Enc UTF8 -Append $OutputFile
    }
}
```

The input will be a text file which has a bunch of IP addresses and HostName. 
The script should be able to read/recognize both of them and check whether the host is online/offline.

Comment: So what exactly is failing in your script? What is the part you require help with?

Comment: `Test-Connection` works with both IP Addresses and hostnames. Exactly like `ping.exe`. There is no need for any DNS shenanigans. Look at the "aliases" list under `Get-Help Test-Connection -Parameter ComputerName`

Comment: In other words: Yes, the name of the parameter `ComputerName` is confusing, but you your real mistake was that haven't read the documentation. It's possible that your local help is incomplete. To fix this, start a PowerShell as admin and run `Update-Help` once. After that you can call `Get-Help Test-Connection -Examples` to see usage examples and `Get-Help Test-Connection -Parameter ComputerName` will explicitly say that IP Addresses are allowed.

Comment: I can't start a PowerShell as admin as I don't have the accesses here. Any other suggestion that might work? thank you for your time.